# API Yandex Metrika внешние переходы

Tags: yandex-metrika-api

Задача следующая:
Достать отчет `внешние переходы` с помощью `API`.
Необходимо `dimensions = 'внешняя ссылка', metrics = 'количество переходов'`.
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

В общем выяснил - данный отчет невозможно вытянуть с помощью API. 
Такой ответ дали с тех. поддержки yandex:

[image: ответ yandex]

Как вариант - использовать Logs API [Документация](https://tech.yandex.ru/metrika/doc/api2/logs/intro-docpage/)